# je anders gedacht zu haben

Tags: grammatical-case

Why do we use 'zu haben' and what kind of grammatical construction is used in this sentence:

> "Manchmal überrumpelte er einen, indem er schlagartig die Position des anderen zu seiner eigenen machte und abstritt, je anders gedacht zu haben." (Steve Jobs, Die autorisierte Biografie des Apple-Gründers, s. 146)

I understand everything before

```
je anders gedacht zu haben
```

But then I'm missing kind of grammatical construct used there. Maybe it is some kind of idiomatical construction?

Comment: Not very different from the English construction, "to have thought otherwise", where you also use the infinitive of "have" together with "to".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortened sentence:

> Er stritt ab, je anders gedacht zu haben.
>   He denied ever having thought otherwise.

This construction is called *»Infinitivsatz«*. You can replace it with a *dass-Satz (Nebensatz, der mit »dass« eingeleitet wird)*:

> Er stritt ab, dass er je anders gedacht hat.
>   He denied that he ever had thought otherwise.